# Conditioned input with arrays

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I have this code and I want it to ask the user repeatedly to input a number repand want each number to be stored in an array until the user enters 0 and then print out the result but it doesn't seem to work

I would also like to add that I am not trying to use pointers. This assignment requires us to do it without pointers.

this is my code:

```
printf("Enter your commands\n");
int input;

int commandArray[10];

    for (size_t i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &input) != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            scanf("%d", &input);
            commandArray[i] = input;
        }
    }


for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", commandArray[i]);
}
```

This is the output I want

(User enters) :
1
4
5
3
6
0(to stop adding elements into array)

(Program shows elements in the array):

1 4 5 3 6

Comment: `if (scanf("%d", &input) != 0)` - I don't think it is doing what you intended it to do. Please read up on the return value of `scanf`, It is *not* the value which is inputed.

Comment: You want `if( scanf(...) != 1 )` or `if( input == 0 )`

Comment: Yes you were right my bad; fixed it now but it still doesn't work just keeps on letting me type in numbers even after I hit 0. @WilliamPursell

Comment: Because you don't check for input being zero.

Comment: In your loop, you call `scanf` and read a value.  If that read was successful, you then discard that value and read another.  You probably don't intend to be discarding every other input.

Comment: This will only work for arrays of size 10. What if you get 11 numbers as input? Maybe use dynamic memory allocation for your array?

Comment: Editing the basic mistakes in your code is counterproductive once people begin to comment and answer your question.  Edits to original post should be reserved to formatting improvements, or adding additional content, eg for clarification in response to a question in comments, or other _new_ information.  Otherwise you create a moving target, and invalidate many of the points that are being make in the effort to help.  (For these reasons I have rolled your code back to its original content.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf doesn't return the read value,it just saves it in the input variable.

Also when you print the array at the end you always print the full array even if the user added less than 10 numbers,you should save the size of the array in a different variable.

Lastly you should stop the cycle when input is equal to 0,not when it's different.

This is the working code

```
printf("Enter your commands\n");
int input;

int commandArray[10];
int size = 0;

    for (size_t i =0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        
        size = i;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        
        if (input == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            commandArray[i] = input;
        }
    }


for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", commandArray[i]);
}
```